# What language is Visual Studio 2010/2012 written in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Visual Studio has historically been C++, but is there any C# or VB.NET code in versions 2010 and 2012?

Does it require the CLR to function?

Thanks

Comment: It's written in a lot of languages:  Visual Studio is composed of many different parts, and different parts utilize different languages and technologies.  Visual Studio is also extensible, and you can write your own extension in pretty much whatever language you'd like.  And, yes, .NET is required.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

C++ and C#

Look at the sidebar in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)

Comment: Do you know which parts are written in C#? Is it mostly the WPF UI portions? I'd think a lot of the WPF code is actually in C++

Comment: Seeing as they don't release the source for VS2012 (and they never will), it will be hard to figure out for sure.

Comment: I did some more research. A lot of the VS UI is actually now written in C#/VB.NET. They're moving further towards managed languages, but they obviously didn't want to throw out their older codebase, so there's still a ton of legacy and newly added C++.

Comment: Having used it and Eclipse, it's possible that the C++ accounts for some of the performance difference vs an IDE written in managed code only.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Output window is written in C/C++.
When I tried:

```
string str="The quick brown fox \0 jumps over the lazy dog.";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

The output window for "Debug" shows: "The quick brown fox".

Comment: but not in visual studio 2017

Answer (score 4):

[The Programming Languages Beacon](http://www.lextrait.com/Vincent/implementations.html) website contains a nice table of a whole bunch of different products and the languages they are written in. According to this site, Visual Studio is, indeed, written in C# and C++.