# why visual studio devenv.exe is not .net module

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-reflector

Visual Studio is build on .NET framework and (WPF / XAML). But if we try to use the reflection tool like .NET reflector for devenv.exe (visual studio process) why it says not a valid .NET module.

Comment: I don't accept your premise.

Comment: @SamAxe what is benefit of having the windows native executable as oppose to .net executable.

Comment: *Visual Studio is build on .NET framework* Citation or it didn't happen... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706149/what-language-is-visual-studio-2010-2012-written-in The accepted respone for VS 2012 was C++ + C#, so devenv.exe could be the C++ part.

Comment: VS is at its core a plugin host, it uses COM to get plugins loaded and talking to each other.  Written in C++.  It also supports writing plugins in .NET.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for sharing more inside on this.

Answer (score 1):

By taking a look at the dependancies of `devenv.exe` (for example with [Dependancy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)) I see that it depends on

- vcruntime140.dll
- msvcp140.dll
- mscoree.dll

This is compatible with what you obtain if you write a C++/CLR app ("mixed" mode, so the default one, where the program is compiled to machine code and can use both native libraries and .NET libraries, not the "safe" or the "pure" one).